# Prove that If a closed curve on the unit sphere has length less than $2\pi$, then it is contained in some hemisphere.

Tags: geometry

I found the following proof in a book:

"Pick any point P on the curve, travel half way around the curve to the
point $Q$, and let $N$ (standing for North Pole) be the point half-way between $P$ and $Q$. (Since the distance $d(P,Q)$ from $P$ to $Q$ is less than $\pi$, $N$ is uniquely defined). $N$ determines an “equator” and if the curve lies entirely in the northern hemisphere, we are done. Otherwise, the curve crosses the equator, and let $E$ be one of the points at which it does so. Then, we observe that $d(E,P) + d(E,Q) = \pi$, since if you poke $P$ through the equatorial plane to $P'$ on the other side, $P'$ is antipodal to $Q$; hence, $d(E,P') + d(E,Q) = \pi$.
However, for any point $X$ on the curve, $d(P,X)+d(X,Q)$ must be less
than $\pi$, and this provides the desired contradiction."

I don't quite understand how this works. I guess the idea is to construct a hemisphere so that the curve lies in it. But how does $N$ determine an equator? Don't we need at least need two Points?
And how does $d(E,P') + d(E,Q) = \pi$ indicate $d(E,P) + d(E,Q) = \pi$ ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't if it correct but my thought on this. In a sphere the longest curve is the curve that is right at the center, and the length of all other curves will be in set $[0, a]$ where $a$ is the length of the largest of them. In a unit circle at longest length will be $2\pi$ so the range of all other curves will be in set $[0, 2\pi]$. So all the curves of length less than $2\pi$ will be in either hemisphere.

Comment: One pole determines the other pole, and the equator is the set of points equidistant from the two poles.

Comment: @ ritwik sinha : the curve doesn't need to be a circle in any way. just needs to be closed.
@MJD: makes sense. 
how do you find $d(E,P) + d(E,Q) = \pi$ though?

Comment: @J.Doe: What book is the proof from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm referring to the following figure. The given loop has the same length $<\pi$ from $P$ to $Q$ along both connecting arcs. It follows that the spherical distance $d(P,Q)<\pi$, so that there is a unique great circle containing $P$ and $Q$, and there is a north pole $N$ midway on the shorter great circle arc connecting $P$ and $Q$. The eqator plane belonging to this north pole $N$ is depicted as a horizontal line in the figure. Reflect $P$ in the equator plane to obtain $P'$, which is antipodal to $Q$.

If the given loop intersects the equator in a point $E$ then
$$d(P,E)+d(E,Q)=d(P',E)+d(E,Q)\geq d(P',Q)=\pi\ .\tag{1}$$
On the other hand $d(P,E)+d(E,Q)$ is at most equal to half the length of the loop, hence $<\pi$. Together with $(1)$ we have a contradiction, hence such a point $E$ cannot exist.

[image]

Comment: This is a very clear explanation. Is there a known reference of this proof in the literature?